# Disable Sendmail from rescue mode CentOS 6 Virtual Server

Tags: centos-6, sendmail, rescue

Hello we rent a virtual server of 1and1 CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 12 (64-bit)

they have put it into rescue mode as it was "found to be part of a network of compromised machines leading a Denial-of-Service Attack (DoS-Attack) against other servers." 
We cant access the server normally until its been fixed.

I currently have access via rescue mode. The root directory from the VServer is mounted to /mnt

They kindly sent this dump:

```
- Details about the malicious processes:
List of malicious processes:===============================
79405009 root  63721  0.3  0.0 114580 33932 ?  D    May01 00:06:01 sendmail: ./u3S78V7U009014 from queue
79405009 root  43601  0.4  0.0 114536 33804 ?  D    May01 00:06:01 sendmail: ./u3S7GSjD009908 from queue
79405009 root  52161  0.3  0.0 114548 33952 ?  D    May01 00:05:42 sendmail: ./u3SEPxEx031537 mx4.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  12349  0.3  0.0 114248 33612 ?  S    May01 00:05:31 sendmail: ./u3SKWist013960 beer.com.: user open
79405009 root  35948  0.3  0.0 114868 34028 ?  S    May01 00:05:13 sendmail: ./u3SMgtPj030769 gogo.mn.: user open
79405009 root  59426  0.3  0.0 114908 34172 ?  D    May01 00:04:40 sendmail: ./u3TASPHs002157 mx1.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  61306  0.3  0.0 114664 33868 ?  S    May01 00:04:39 sendmail: ./u3T8f62p019985 mx1.breakthru.com.: user open
79405009 root   1611  0.3  0.0 114440 33792 ?  S    May01 00:03:47 sendmail: ./u3TMkZM2028370 mx1.hotmail.com.: client greeting
79405009 root   6664  0.3  0.0 114560 33868 ?  D    May01 00:04:09 sendmail: ./u3TLL0t2018878 from queue
79405009 root   2345  0.2  0.0 114864 34176 ?  S    May01 00:02:56 sendmail: ./u3UDLWT0010488 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root   5262  0.3  0.0 114960 34288 ?  S    May01 00:03:44 sendmail: ./u3U4HRpn003520 mail2.siteamerica.com.: user open
79405009 root  19138  0.3  0.0 115508 34780 ?  S    May01 00:03:15 sendmail: ./u3UC3QYX002579 mx2.hotmail.com.: client EHLO
79405009 root  34044  0.3  0.0 115072 34292 ?  D    May01 00:03:09 sendmail: ./u3UDdBA5012117 from queue
79405009 root  39121  0.3  0.0 114992 34272 ?  D    00:43 00:02:57 sendmail: ./u3UG0NMv026076 from queue
79405009 root  34198  0.3  0.0 115188 34400 ?  D    01:43 00:02:49 sendmail: ./u3UKxATO003157 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root  25110  0.3  0.0 115236 34460 ?  S    02:43 00:02:29 sendmail: ./u3UM7mJk010596 mx3.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  34060  0.3  0.0 115516 34712 ?  D    03:43 00:02:20 sendmail: ./u410hmIn031536 from queue
79405009 root  24722  0.3  0.0 116004 35280 ?  R    04:43 00:02:05 sendmail: ./u416lHtr015928 mx1.hotmail.com.: user open
79405009 root    765  0.3  0.0 115828 34984 ?  D    05:43 00:01:49 sendmail: ./u41AJE2I012024 mx4.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  26444  0.3  0.0 115724 34928 ?  D    06:43 00:01:35 sendmail: ./u41HYq5G003987 from queue
79405009 root  12117  0.3  0.0 115552 34884 ?  D    07:43 00:01:20 sendmail: ./u41HkH7U005386 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root  44179  0.3  0.0 114976 34212 ?  S    08:43 00:01:09 sendmail: ./u41LioD9004030 mta5.am0.yahoodns.net.: client EHLO

root@hn1512:~$ find /vz/root/79405009/var/spool/mqueue|wc -l
533259


PROCESSES:
==================
 CTID USER       PID %CPU %MEM   VSZ  RSS TTY  STAT START     TIME COMMAND
79405009 root  36122  0.0  0.0 19236 1120 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:26 init
79405009 root  36139  0.0  0.0     0    0 ?    S    Apr23 00:00:00 [kthreadd/794050]
79405009 root  36140  0.0  0.0     0    0 ?    S    Apr23 00:00:00 [khelper/7940500]
79405009 root  38593  0.0  0.0 10644  352 ?    S<s  Apr23 00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d
79405009 root  40741  0.0  0.0 345728 13700 ?  Ss   Apr23 00:00:19 /usr/bin/sw-engine -c /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/modules/watchdog/wdcollect -c /usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/wdcollect.inc.php
79405009 root  41870  0.7  0.0 184328 5560 ?   Sl   Apr23 01:33:17 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5
79405009 dbus  42170  0.0  0.0 21436  368 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system
79405009 root  42259  0.0  0.0 66228  580 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:12 /usr/sbin/sshd
79405009 root  42367  0.0  0.0 66412  284 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam -n 2
79405009 root  42369  0.0  0.0 66412   32 ?    S    Apr23 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -m /var/run/saslauthd -a pam -n 2
79405009 root  42659  0.0  0.0 82644 1672 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:04:13 sendmail: accepting connections
79405009 smmsp 42792  0.0  0.0 78236 1592 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue
79405009 root  43545  0.0  0.0 332044 25092 ?  Ss   Apr23 00:00:21 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 root  44966  0.0  0.0 11308  788 ?    S    Apr23 00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
79405009 mysql 45316  0.0  0.0 1023024 37528 ? Sl   Apr23 00:06:18 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
79405009 root  48599  0.0  0.0 116864 900 ?    Ss   Apr23 00:00:18 crond
79405009 root  48608  0.0  0.0 195696 2732 ?   Ssl  Apr23 00:00:49 /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/modules/watchdog/monit -Ic /usr/local/psa/etc/modules/watchdog/monitrc
79405009 root  41790  0.0  0.0 44964 1424 ?    Ss   Apr25 00:00:00 sw-cp-server: master process /usr/sbin/sw-cp-serverd -c /etc/sw-cp-server/config
79405009 497   41797  0.0  0.0 45420 3044 ?    S    Apr25 00:00:00 sw-cp-server: worker process                       
79405009 root  43406  0.0  0.0 21720  992 ?    Ss   Apr29 00:00:00 xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
79405009 root  14301  0.0  0.0 350868 9064 ?   Ss   Apr29 00:00:00 sw-engine-fpm: master process (/etc/sw-engine/sw-engine-fpm.conf)                                          
79405009 root  41948  0.3  0.0 114792 33992 ?  S    May01 00:07:06 sendmail: ./u3RGw45P031441 mail.gnail.com.: user open
79405009 root  12946  0.4  0.0 114816 33984 ?  S    May01 00:07:00 sendmail: ./u3RJ6P1J015717 mx2.hotmail.com.: user open
79405009 root  61532  0.3  0.0 114728 33948 ?  D    May01 00:06:43 sendmail: ./u3RNPKLg014912 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root   3692  0.3  0.0 114652 33960 ?  S    May01 00:05:52 sendmail: ./u3SB27wO005821 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 apache 32306  0.0  0.0 237004 13856 ? S    May01 00:00:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 root  63721  0.3  0.0 114580 33932 ?  D    May01 00:06:02 sendmail: ./u3S6NC3T004736 from queue
79405009 root  43601  0.4  0.0 114536 33804 ?  S    May01 00:06:01 sendmail: ./u3S7EHWh009648 mx3.hotmail.com.: user open
79405009 root  52161  0.3  0.0 114548 33952 ?  S    May01 00:05:43 sendmail: ./u3SDB6Fb021778 mx.sprintpcs.com.: user open
79405009 root  12349  0.3  0.0 114248 33612 ?  S    May01 00:05:31 sendmail: ./u3SKWist013960 beer.com.: user open
79405009 root  35948  0.3  0.0 114868 34028 ?  S    May01 00:05:13 sendmail: ./u3T0rKpL013515 mx2.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  59426  0.3  0.0 114908 34172 ?  S    May01 00:04:40 sendmail: ./u3T9Kos9026795 sashi.com.: user open
79405009 root  61306  0.3  0.0 114664 33868 ?  S    May01 00:04:39 sendmail: ./u3T8f62p019985 mx1.breakthru.com.: user open
79405009 root   1611  0.3  0.0 114440 33792 ?  S    May01 00:03:47 sendmail: ./u3TMkSi7028322 mx3.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root   6664  0.3  0.0 114560 33868 ?  S    May01 00:04:09 sendmail: ./u3U11HcB013813 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client EHLO
79405009 root   2345  0.2  0.0 114864 34176 ?  D    May01 00:02:56 sendmail: ./u3UDVu1p011442 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root   5262  0.3  0.0 114960 34288 ?  S    May01 00:03:44 sendmail: ./u3U4HRpn003520 mail2.siteamerica.com.: user open
79405009 root  19138  0.3  0.0 115508 34780 ?  S    May01 00:03:15 sendmail: ./u3U9wUr3019601 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.: user open
79405009 root  34044  0.3  0.0 115072 34292 ?  D    May01 00:03:09 sendmail: ./u3UDrYjn013660 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root  39121  0.3  0.0 114992 34272 ?  D    00:43 00:02:57 sendmail: ./u3UEDHB1015373 from queue
79405009 root  34198  0.3  0.0 115188 34400 ?  D    01:43 00:02:50 sendmail: ./u3UKZf2a000339 mta6.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 root  25110  0.3  0.0 115236 34460 ?  S    02:43 00:02:29 sendmail: ./u3UM5MjA010297 mx3.hotmail.com.: user open
79405009 root  34060  0.3  0.0 115516 34712 ?  D    03:43 00:02:20 sendmail: ./u410hmJN031536 from queue
79405009 root  24722  0.3  0.0 116000 35276 ?  D    04:43 00:02:05 sendmail: ./u419etov007939 mx1.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root    765  0.3  0.0 115828 34984 ?  S    05:43 00:01:49 sendmail: ./u419pFGH009313 mx2.hotmail.com.: user open
79405009 root  26444  0.3  0.0 115724 34928 ?  D    06:43 00:01:36 sendmail: ./u41GsI4I000523 from queue
79405009 root  12117  0.3  0.0 115552 34884 ?  S    07:43 00:01:20 sendmail: ./u41I2Lg0007106 mx4.hotmail.com.: client greeting
79405009 root  44179  0.3  0.0 114976 34212 ?  S    08:43 00:01:09 sendmail: ./u41NRUWX019486 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client MAIL
79405009 apache 64470  0.0  0.0 332308 17988 ? S    09:43 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 root   1739  0.4  0.0 115232 34568 ?  S    09:43 00:01:01 sendmail: ./u421eQ0C001701 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client EHLO
79405009 root  35706  0.5  0.0 115084 34340 ?  S    10:43 00:00:56 sendmail: ./u422RGJx007171 mx4.hotmail.com.: client EHLO
79405009 root  22405  0.5  0.0 115384 34576 ?  S    11:43 00:00:44 sendmail: ./u423w4fh018233 mta7.am0.yahoodns.net.: client greeting
79405009 apache 36495  0.0  0.0 332716 18412 ? S    12:00 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 apache 36616  0.0  0.0 332176 17636 ? S    12:00 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 apache 2911  0.0  0.0 332328 17976 ?  S    12:34 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 apache 11548  0.0  0.0 332324 17676 ? S    12:36 00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
79405009 root  41863  0.6  0.0 115296 34540 ?  S    12:43 00:00:24 sendmail: ./u428k2sq021102 mx4.hotmail.com.: client MAIL
79405009 root  22811  4.5  0.0 114660 34020 ?  D    13:43 00:00:11 sendmail: ./u42B8Ktp009491 from queue
79405009 smmsp 22820  0.0  0.0 78332 2476 ?    S    13:43 00:00:00 sendmail: ./u3RKKEoo023232 from queue      
79405009 root  23250  0.0  0.0 82812 3336 ?    S    13:43 00:00:00 sendmail: server localhost [127.0.0.1] cmd re
```

So it looks like sendmail is the cause of the problem.

We are ditching this server we just need to get a mysqldump of 2 databases on mysql data off it (which we can't access in rescue mode )

Ideally if possible i would like to remove sendmail from the box and then presumably as sendmail no longer exists they can put the box back online so i can get into phpmyadmin and dump the databases i need.

How can i remove sendmail from rescue mode? or is there something else i could try?

Comment: Ask your hosting company.

Comment: The hosting company is 1and1 first thing i did was ask them, they do not offer support on this as its not a managed box - they are of little or no help!

Comment: "We cant access the server until its been fixed." If you can't access the server you can't fix it. You need their help.

Comment: sorry i do have access to it in rescue mode via ssh or winscp, updated the question to show that!